# Symfony app: For each HTTP GET, there are 2 HTTP HEAD: why?

Tags: http, symfony, get

I've juste realised that on my new project on `symfony 2.6`, each time I'm doing a `GET` on an url, automatically after, there are 2 `HEAD` on the same request.

But I can't manage to figure why? Neither where to start to fing where does come that issue from?

Does someone know where I can start digging from on that one ?

Here is an extract off my `access` log :

```
::1 - - [05/Feb/2015:02:06:31 +0100] "GET /tvjp/demande/lister HTTP/1.1" 200 49930
::1 - - [05/Feb/2015:02:06:34 +0100] "HEAD /tvjp/demande/lister HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::1 - - [05/Feb/2015:02:06:37 +0100] "HEAD /tvjp/demande/lister HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::1 - - [05/Feb/2015:02:07:02 +0100] "GET /tvjp/ws/requests HTTP/1.1" 200 201
::1 - - [05/Feb/2015:02:07:05 +0100] "HEAD /tvjp/ws/requests HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::1 - - [05/Feb/2015:02:07:07 +0100] "HEAD /tvjp/ws/requests HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::1 - - [05/Feb/2015:02:12:33 +0100] "GET /tvjp/demande/editer HTTP/1.1" 200 1080
::1 - - [05/Feb/2015:02:12:42 +0100] "HEAD /tvjp/demande/editer HTTP/1.1" 500 -
::1 - - [05/Feb/2015:02:12:45 +0100] "HEAD /tvjp/demande/editer HTTP/1.1" 500 -
::1 - - [05/Feb/2015:02:12:49 +0100] "GET /tvjp/ws/requests/136 HTTP/1.1" 200 39
::1 - - [05/Feb/2015:02:12:54 +0100] "HEAD /tvjp/ws/requests/136 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::1 - - [05/Feb/2015:02:12:56 +0100] "HEAD /tvjp/ws/requests/136 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not connected with Symfony Framework. What web-browser are you using ?? Have You maybe opened developer console in your web-browser ?? Have you installed any plugins in browser?? Try another browser and check your access log.

Comment: You're right !!! I can't reproduce that on firefox. I was on chrome browser. I lost my time for nothing. Thank you very much.